If $A \in M_n(\mathbb K)$ is not full rank, it exists $M \in M_n(\mathbb K)$ with $\det( M + \lambda A) \neq 0$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb K$
Let $\mathbb K$ be a field and $A \in M_n(\mathbb K)$ a squared matrix with entries in $\mathbb K$ that is not full rank. The aim is to show that $M \in M_n(\mathbb K)$ exists with $\det( M + \lambda A) \neq 0$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb K$.
I found the following solution:

Let $r \lt n$ be the rank of $A$. Given the hypothesis on $A$, we can suppose that $A$ is the matrix $J_r$ having all entries equal to zero, except the $r$ first ones on the diagonal that are equal to one. The matrix $M$ having all entries equal to zero except that $m_{i+1, i} =m_{1,n}=1$ for $1 \le i \lt n-1$ is a solution.

However, I would like to know if a more geometric solution can be found. I mean: if $u$ is a singular linear operator of a finite-dimensional space $E$ (i.e. $u(E) = F \subsetneq E$), how to build a linear operator $v$ of $E$ such that $v + \lambda u$ is invertible for any $\lambda \in \mathbb K$? By geometric, I mean without using a basis.

Same idea? Let $U$ be a subspace of $E$ such that $F\oplus U = E$. Then let $v$ be any linear operator whose image is $U$. Then the image of $v+\lambda u$ is $U+\lambda F = U+F= E$. If you have an inner product, you can even let $U=F^{\perp}$ and $v$ the orthogonal projection onto $U$.

Hmmm ... not sure about this. Take for $K$ complex numbers. Then determinant is a polynomial in $\lambda$ so having no zero means it is constant (and not zero).

@ArturoMagidin Almost good... the issue is that it fails for $\lambda = 0$.

@Salcio Except if the polynomial is constant and non-zero. This is the case for the solution I provided.

By the $\lambda=0$ case $M$ must be invertible. Then, supposing $\lambda\neq 0$ we need $\mathop{det}(\lambda^{-1}I+ M^{-1}A)$ nonzero for every $\lambda\neq0$, which implies it must be $\lambda^{-n}$ (since it's a monic polynomial in $\lambda^{-1}$ of degree $n$), ie $M^{-1}A$ is nilpotent. That's as far as I got without picking a basis, but it at least gives a more geometric interpretation of the answer :~)
